# Issues installing MySQL server on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I'm currently trying to install a MySQL server on my Ubuntu 13.04 machine. The problem is, when I try to install it, I get error messages indicating that not all packages could be downloaded. When I run `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, and after hanging for a while at reading headers, the console reads as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18 libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
  libipc-sharedcache-perl tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18 libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 8,077 kB/24.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 84.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Err http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-updates/main mysql-client-5.5 i386 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main mysql-client-5.5 i386 5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.5/mysql-client-5.5_5.5.32-0ubuntu0.13.04.1_i386.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.190 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I've tried the suggested fix or running apt-get update and such, I've made sure I have no connections blocked, I've restarted, uninstalled, reinstalled, etc, all to no avail. I've been searching the web all day for solutions I haven't yet tried, but most people with this issue are running an older version of Ubuntu. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this isn't an Internet connection issue ("Connection failed" is a needlessly obscure message), then this looks like a problem with the particular Ubuntu mirrors your system is trying to use, rather than something specific to MySQL.

The answer posted on [What to try when apt-get install xxx Results in Connection Failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88992/what-to-try-when-apt-get-install-xxx-results-in-connection-failed) seems like it should get you pointed in the correct direction to resolve this.

It's also possible that `sudo apt-get update` might fix your problem now, even if it didn't fix your problem before, since some time has passed.  I'm speculating, but it could be that if the information fetched by the update operation causes your system behave differently when it's trying to fetch the files you're needing to install, that might also resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

first of all check your internet connection through terminal

```
$ ping www.google.com
```

if it is ok, you are getting reply, then try with

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

then if something goes wrong, install missing packages as,

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
```

If still it doesn't work try with

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score -1):

[Please see this website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302742/unable-to-install-mysql-server-on-ubuntu) as I think it may answer your question.

It may be a problem that you are missing sources.

If that doesn't solve your issue, try posting on that website (it's a part of stackexchange).